# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Unable to deploy upgraded project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

After I migrated my project Worklight from version 6.0 to 6.1, the following error is occurring when trying to deploy the application:

> [2013-12-19 11:37:02] FWLST1040E: android build failed: Cannot
>   overwrite template file
>   'C:\workspaces\worklight\CISSMartTax\apps\CISSMartTax\android\native\native.iml'

Comment: I was using Worklight Shell Component, and was at version 6.0, updated it, and went back to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this currently works for me.

1. In Worklight 6.0.0.1 I've created a new Worklight project and application with the Android environment, built and deployed it
2. I then exported the Worklight project as a .zip file
3. In Worklight 6.1.0 I've imported the above .zipped project, built and deployed it
4. Ran the generated Android project in the Android emulator

This was with a blank new app; it's possible yours is more intricate than that.

Suggestions:

- Delete the native folder and re-build and deploy.

  - Make sure to back-up any native Java classes and other artifacts you may have previously added to the native folder.
- Provide your Worklight project (the original from 6.0.0.x) in a Dropbox download link for analysis...